# The system is going down for halt NOW 40x

Tags: linux, centos, shutdown

I have a CentOS 6.10 machine. Yesterday at 6AM it did one of these:

reboot   system boot  2.6.32-754.23.1. Thu Nov 21 06:07 - 06:07  (00:00)

So we figured glitch, old server, not a huge deal.

It ended up rebooting itself about every 90 minutes until Nov 22 at 4AM when it halted itself.

So when we came in today we updated all of the firmware on the server, etc and when I was logged into the server via SSH. It posted exactly 40 messages like this on the console:

The system is going down for halt NOW!

Broadcast message from root@host
        (unknown) at 13:03 ...

There really aren't any logs that I can find that explain this. This machine has Dell OpenManage on it (its an R330) which has the capability to halt on events but it's totally disabled. I just found it oddly specific that it would send 40 notices that it is going to halt, not 39, or 41, but 40.

We're preparing to just move the drives to another identical machine since this seems like some sort of hardware issue and we have dozens of them but if anyone has any additional things I could look at I would appreciate your advice.

Thanks!

Comment: does it actually halt, and were all of the messages in quick succession (a broadcast flood?). I saw a person years ago on centods who had unplanned halts happening on a headless system that turned out to be resolved by connecting a keyboard, mouse, and monitor and dismissing a dialog on the login screen about language preferences.

Comment: Yeah it actually did HALT and the messages came in a steady pace about 1 per second and it just kept dinging my console over and over. It's a normal system and doesn't have any kind of UI software asking questions, etc.

Comment: I looked at the sflow that we capture from all of our machines' network interfaces and it's not like someone external was in the box making it halt or anything.

Comment: I just halted it myself from SSH and the message is actually:Broadcast message from root@host
        (/dev/pts/1) at 15:16 ...

Comment: is it on a UPS (battery backup?).

Comment: It is but there is no UPS software on the machine that would accept an alert from a UPS system, etc. There are 980 machines being powered by that UPS that didn't halt so it's something with this quirky little fellow.